# Zend Framework 2 autoloading issue

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework2, entity, autoload

When developing on my local computer (MAMP), zf2 will load this class fine but when it's placed onto the server it doesn't work.

The class I created is just a normal PHP class and it's in the following directory. The namespace is declared and correct.

```
module/ModuleName/src/Entity/TheEntity.php
```

I'm trying to access this class from the model (some file in src/Model/SomeModelFile.php). I have a using statement after the namespace declaration in this file.

```
namespace ModuleName\Model;
use ModuleName\Entity\TheEntity;
```

On my local machine I can instantiate this object from the model but on the server I am using I can not. When instantiating this object I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'ModuleName\Entity\TheEntity' not found...
```

I ran composer again in order to ensure that the autoload files are rebuilt, and it runs - this is the output:

```
php composer.phar install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

I also created a new, blank entity called "testEntity" in the same src/Entity directory, this also worked fine on my local computer but failed on the server. Both servers are running the same version of PHP, but there are some configuration differences.

What should I look for, any ideas what could be causing this?

---

**Update**

I've been using git to automatically deploy files onto the server, what happens is the repository is cloned and then composer is run.
I copied my files directly over to the webserver without running composer & everything worked. After doing a bit of digging, I found that vendor/composer/autoload_real.php is different on each. When composer is run, it updates this file and that does not work (requiring the use of autoload_static.php).

What could cause this to happen, which files should I check for composer configuration?

Here is the working version generated by composer on my laptop:

```
<?php

// autoload_real.php @generated by Composer

class ComposerAutoloaderInitc3e0a30879285d1b7c445edcf1beee91
{
    private static $loader;

    public static function loadClassLoader($class)
    {
        if ('Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader' === $class) {
            require __DIR__ . '/ClassLoader.php';
        }
    }

    public static function getLoader()
    {
        if (null !== self::$loader) {
            return self::$loader;
        }

        spl_autoload_register(array('ComposerAutoloaderInitc3e0a30879285d1b7c445edcf1beee91', 'loadClassLoader'), true, true);
        self::$loader = $loader = new \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader();
        spl_autoload_unregister(array('ComposerAutoloaderInitc3e0a30879285d1b7c445edcf1beee91', 'loadClassLoader'));

        $vendorDir = dirname(__DIR__);
        $baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

        $map = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_namespaces.php';
        foreach ($map as $namespace => $path) {
            $loader->set($namespace, $path);
        }

        $map = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_psr4.php';
        foreach ($map as $namespace => $path) {
            $loader->setPsr4($namespace, $path);
        }

        $classMap = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php';
        if ($classMap) {
            $loader->addClassMap($classMap);
        }

        $loader->register(true);

        return $loader;
    }
 }

function composerRequirec3e0a30879285d1b7c445edcf1beee91($file)
{
    require $file;
}
```

And here is the one that does not work (generated by the server)

```
<?php
//on Server (DEV)
// autoload_real.php @generated by Composer

class ComposerAutoloaderInit2d27d41ac16b73f0303f55e7010dca0c
{
    private static $loader;

    public static function loadClassLoader($class)
    {
        if ('Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader' === $class) {
            require __DIR__ . '/ClassLoader.php';
        }
    }

    public static function getLoader()
    {
        if (null !== self::$loader) {
            return self::$loader;
        }

        spl_autoload_register(array('ComposerAutoloaderInit2d27d41ac16b73f0303f55e7010dca0c', 'loadClassLoader'), true, true);
        self::$loader = $loader = new \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader();
        spl_autoload_unregister(array('ComposerAutoloaderInit2d27d41ac16b73f0303f55e7010dca0c', 'loadClassLoader'));

        $useStaticLoader = PHP_VERSION_ID >= 50600 && !defined('HHVM_VERSION') && (!function_exists('zend_loader_file_encoded') || !zend_loader_file_encoded());
        var_dump($useStaticLoader);
        exit;
        if ($useStaticLoader) {
            require_once __DIR__ . '/autoload_static.php';

            call_user_func(\Composer\Autoload\ComposerStaticInit2d27d41ac16b73f0303f55e7010dca0c::getInitializer($loader));
        } else {
            $map = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_namespaces.php';
            foreach ($map as $namespace => $path) {
                $loader->set($namespace, $path);
            }

            $map = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_psr4.php';
            foreach ($map as $namespace => $path) {
                $loader->setPsr4($namespace, $path);
            }

            $classMap = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php';
            if ($classMap) {
                $loader->addClassMap($classMap);
            }
        }

        $loader->register(true);

        return $loader;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the case of the filename definitely match the class name (as in your example)? These kinds of problems are almost always caused by people developing on a case insensitive file system (Windows/Mac) and uploading to a case sensitive one (Linux).

Comment: Yeah it is.  I'll update my question as I literally just found something that is part of the issue I think.

Comment: Can you check the version of composer on local and server?(composer -v) though I doupt this is the problem.

Comment: So as @TimFountain pointed out with the case sensitivity...
Turns out when I originally created these classes the filenames were lowercase. I almost immediately changed it to uppercase, but being on a case insensitive system, GIT never recognized this as a change.

When I deployed the site using automatic deployment the two class files were deployed as lowercase, but locally they were correctly spelled...

Thanks!

Comment: what does your module module.php look like ? Are you sure that you are loading your module configuration ? Did you add your module to the application config ?